# PHP google drive api create spreadsheet

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I need to create spreadsheet using google drive PHP API, how can i do that ?
i already have code put it always get untitled file and when i click on it there is no data here is my code:

```
/**
* Insert new file.
*
* @param apiDriveService $service Drive API service instance.
* @param string $title Title of the file to insert, including the extension.
* @param string $description Description of the file to insert.
* @param string $parentId Parent folder's ID.
* @param string $mimeType MIME type of the file to insert.
* @param string $filename Filename of the file to insert.
* @return DriveFile The file that was inserted. NULL is returned if an API error occurred.
*/
function insertFile($service, $title, $description, $parentId, $mimeType, $data) {
$file = new DriveFile();
$file->setTitle($title);
$file->setDescription($description);
$file->setMimeType($mimeType);

// Set the parent folder.
if ($parentId != null) {
    $parentsCollectionData = new DriveFileParentsCollection();
    $parentsCollectionData->setId($parentId);
    $file->setParentsCollection(array($parentsCollectionData));
}

try {

    $createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
        'data' => $data,
        'mimeType' => $mimeType,
    ));

    // Uncomment the following line to print the File ID
    // print 'File ID: %s' % $createdFile->getId();

    print_r($createdFile);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
}
}
if(isset($_POST['insertFile'])){
$service = new apiDriveService($client);
insertFile($service,'Google Maps Mrakers.txt','ADD Google Map Mrakers To File',NULL,'text/plain',$_POST['data']);
exit;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are having this issue because you are using an out-of-date version of the PHP client library. Please sync your client to the trunk of the project [repository](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/checkout).

You would have to re-write some of your code as the client library has been refactored since you first wrote your code. The [reference guides](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference) in the [Google Drive SDK documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive) have been updated to reflect this refactoring.

To create a Google Spreadsheet, insert a file without content with its `mimeType` set to `application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet`.

Comment: Simply set the file's `mimeType` to `application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet`: this will create an empty spreadsheet in the user's Google Drive.

Comment: Thx @Alain for your effort your all answers are correct, put how can i put content in that empty spreadsheet ?

Comment: @AhmedSaber, you will need to use the [Spreadsheets API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/).